# how to create a sequence prediction in keras

Tags: neural-network, sequence, keras

I want to predict an output sequence with keras LSTM. I have 6 features and 6 output values. However my code throws an error in my label values.

```
Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (4000, 6)
```

import numpy as np
    np.random.seed(seed=7)
    import pandas as pd

```
numbers = pd.read_csv(r'C:\...\Desktop\LSTM.csv', sep=';')

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

numval = numbers.values.astype('float32')
scaler =MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit_transform(numval)

X = numval[:4000,0:6]

y = numval[:4000,6:]

y_test = numval[4000,:6:]

X = np.reshape(X,(X.shape[0],1,X.shape[1]))

X_test = numval[4000:,0:6]
X_test  = np.reshape(X_test,(X_test.shape[0],1,X_test.shape[1]))

print(X.shape)


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(6,input_dim=6,stateful=True))
model.add(Dense(6))
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X,y,batch_size=200,nb_epoch=100,verbose=2)
scores =  model.evaluate(X_test,y_test,batch_size=32,verbose=1)
print(scores[1])
```

How can i get multiple labeloutputs? Thx

Comment: Try `y_test = numval[4000,6]`

Comment: Thanks Marcin but receive an error: ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (4000, 6)

Comment: Do the same change with `y`

Comment: Thanks but then i receive this error: ValueError: Error when checking model target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape ()

Comment: Could you print out `x.shape` and `y.shape`?